# How do I assert the type of an inner function depends on the type of the outer function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So, I'm writing a little helper function to do breadth-first searches (just a hobby project):

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Set as S

breadthFirst :: (Monad m, Ord a) => (a -> m [a]) -> [a] -> m ()                                                                                                   
breadthFirst f init = evalStateT (go init) S.empty                                                                                                                
  where                                                                                                                                                            
    go :: [a] -> StateT (S.Set a) m ()                                                                                                                             
    go [] = return ()                                                                                                                                              
    go (x:xs) = do                                                                                                                                                 
      visited <- gets (S.member x)                                                                                                                                       
      if visited then (go xs) else do                                                                                                                                      
        modify (S.insert x)                                                                                                                                        
        lift (f x) >>= (\n -> go (xs++n))
```

I.e. pull states off a queue, run `f` to get more states and put them back on the queue, use a `Set` to keep track of visited states, and whatever side effects `m` provides.

Except it doesn't compile: `Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘m1’` etc etc okay the compiler doesn't think the inner `a` and `m` are the same as the outer `a` and `m` and hence it doesn't think the `f x` call will compile...

But if I delete the type assertion for `go` I get `Non-type variable argument in the constraint` because it infers a too-broad type for `go`:

```
go :: forall (t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *).
          (MonadTrans t, MonadState (S.Set a) (t m)) =>
          [a] -> t m ()
```

I can fix this with `FlexibleContexts` but I *know* the type of `go`, it's not some arbitrary `MonadState` instance, it's just `StateT`. If I replace `return ()` with `StateT $ (\s -> ((), s))` then that give the compiler the extra info it needs but that's a little off-putting too.

Is there a way to just tell the compiler the type signature of `go`, including the fact that the type variables are the same type variables as in the outer function?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables sounds like what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's done via the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. You need to quantify the outer function with `forall`, then the functions defined in the where clause unless they have `forall` themselves will refer to the outer scope. When you don't have scoped type variables, every type signature is implicitly quantified so the variables are potentially different to the compiler.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module SO where

import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Set as S

breadthFirst :: forall m a. (Monad m, Ord a) => (a -> m [a]) -> [a] -> m ()
breadthFirst f init = evalStateT (go init) S.empty
  where
    go :: [a] -> StateT (S.Set a) m ()
    go [] = return ()
    go (x:xs) = do
      visited <- gets (S.member x)
      if visited then (go xs) else do
        modify (S.insert x)
        lift (f x) >>= (\n -> go (xs++n))
```